# Conditional JQuery dropdown for search function

Tags: jquery

I'm building a search function in jQuery. I have 3 dropdowns that are loaded from a MySQLdatabase. When a user selects 1 of the dropdowns it has to affect the other dropdown values.

I made it working for the seperate values but I'm stuck when they select 2 or 3 dropdowns. I worked with the && operator but this doesn't work. Can someone please take a look what im doing wrong?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
    if( $(("#IndID").change) && $(("#CatID").change)) {
    $("#ProdName").load("scriptp.php?c3=" + $("#IndID").val() + $("#CatID").val());
    }

        if( $(("#IndID").change) && $(("#ProdName").change)) {
        $("#CatID").load("scriptc.php?c=" + $("#IndID").val() + $("#ProdName").val());
    }

        $("#IndID").change(function() {
        $("#CatID").load("scripti.php?c=" + $("#IndID").val());
        });

        $("#CatID").change(function() {
            $("#ProdName").load("script.php?cc=" + $("#CatID").val());
        });

    });
</script>
```

Comment: I also have a link for jsfiddle.net: http://jsfiddle.net/QXKMV/3/

Comment: I don't really get what you're after with `$(("#IndID").change) && $(("#CatID").change))`. You meant "if both changes" ?

Comment: Hello Didier, yes if both dropdowns are selected then both variables need to be passed to the script for the third dropdown.

Comment: Well you can't change two dropdown at the same time...

Comment: The idea is that they select 1 dropdown, then the other 2 dropdowns values are changed. if they select a second dropdown the third dropdown values are changed with the selections of the first 2 dropdowns. But any of the 3 dropdowns should affect the other

Comment: Yes but there is a sort-of order to change themlike the DD1 changes the values of the DD2 and then selecting an option in the DD2 changes the values of the DD3. And if you re-change the DD1, the DD3 is reset and the DD2 values re-loaded. Right ?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    // query already the elements you're going to use
    var $ind = $("#IndID"),
        $cat = $("#CatID"),
        $prod = $("#ProdName");

    $ind.change(function(e) {
        // populate the second select
        if ($(this).val() === "") {
            $cat.html('');
        } else {
            $cat.load("scripti.php?c=" + $ind.val());
        }
        // reset the third select
        $prod.html('');
    });

    $cat.change(function(e) {
        // populate the third select
        if ($(this).val() === "") {
            $prod.html('');
        } else {
            $prod.load("scriptc.php?c=" + $ind.val() + $cat.val());
        }
    });

});
```

**Note**: querying the dom is *not efficient* so it is better to query once your static elements and use the jquery objects to work with instead of re-querying all the time.

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/didierg/ZeZuq/)**